# External js library not work when route changes in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, video.js

I am using an external library on my app, I noticed that when I change the route  then return back the library stop working.
The libraries are imported like this:

```
   import videojs from "video.js"
   import  "videojs-markers"
    ....
   ngOnInit() {
      this.video = videojs('demo');
      this.video.on('pause', function () {
        this.onPauseVideo(this.video.currentTime())
      }.bind(this));
      this.video.on('play', function () {
        this.onPlayVideo(this.video.currentTime())
      }.bind(this));

      this.setUpMarkers(this.video);
        this.subscription = this.commentService.commentsChange.subscribe((newComments:VideoComment[])=>{
          this.video.markers.add(newComments.map(el=>{
            return {time:el.time,text:el.text,overlayText:el.overlayText}})
          );

        })
      }


     ....
```

[image]

any suggestions.

Comment: Usually when working when external, you need to be carefull to reset the lib on the `ngOnDestroy` angular callback, to be sure that the next `ngOnInit`works properly.

Comment: how can i do such that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. remove .bind(this) from your code. arrow functional should help
   you.
2. This line move to constructor(){}

   > this.video = videojs('demo');
3. remove all event listeners like this ngOnDestroy(){ this.video.off('pause')